# Getting data of phone with dead battery

Tags: battery, charging, boot-loop, unbricking

I have to get data off an old Zuk Z2 Plus that was working when it got replaced by a new phone and left lieing around for a year or so. Now it does not boot any more. When I plug in power, the screen briefly lights up, shows a 0% charge, vibrates, turns off and then repeats the same thing.

If I press the power button, the boot screen shows up for about 1-2 seconds (about the same time as the charge indicator), then the phone vibrates, turns off, and repeats the charge indicator loop.

I figure, the battery is deep-discharged (0V), so the charge circuit powers up, finds that the battery does not have any voltage at all and then resets.

I could replace the battery, but spending €30+ on a new battery for a phone that will be discarded afterwards is a bit of a waste.

It has a very proprietary battery connector, so attaching some random lipo to the battery port is a bit hard as well.

Do you have any good ideas on how to fix the situation?

Comment: Maybe something here may help https://android.stackexchange.com/q/133851/131553

Comment: i would try to charge battery with external charger. or leave it in loop over night

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/219810